# LeetCode Android Unlock problem 351 > Valid jumps

Tags: algorithm, depth-first-search

One way to unlock an Android phone is through a pattern of swipes across a  `1-9`  keypad.

For a pattern to be valid, it must satisfy the following:

- All of its keys must be distinct.
- It must not connect two keys by jumping over a third key, unless that key has already been used.

For example,  `4 - 2 - 1 - 7`  is a valid pattern, whereas  `2 - 1 - 7`  is not.

Find the total number of valid unlock patterns of length  `N`, where  `1 <= N <= 9`.

**Invalid move:**  `4 - 1 - 3 - 6`
Line 1 - 3 passes through key 2 which had not been selected in the pattern.

**Invalid move:**  `4 - 1 - 9 - 2`
Line 1 - 9 passes through key 5 which had not been selected in the pattern.

**Valid move:**  `2 - 4 - 1 - 3 - 6`
Line 1 - 3 is valid because it passes through key 2, which had been selected in the pattern

**Valid move:**  `6 - 5 - 4 - 1 - 9 - 2`
Line 1 - 9 is valid because it passes through key 5, which had been selected in the pattern.

| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 4 | 5 | 6 |
| 7 | 8 | 9 |

I am able to solve the problem using DFS.  But we have to also consider skip / jump. For solving it, i have seen people saving/using only the following combinations of valid jump.

for e.g

```
int skip[][] = new int[10][10];
skip[1][3] = skip[3][1] = 2;
skip[1][7] = skip[7][1] = 4;
skip[3][9] = skip[9][3] = 6;
skip[7][9] = skip[9][7] = 8;
skip[1][9] = skip[9][1] = skip[2][8] = skip[8][2] = skip[3][7] = skip[7][3] = skip[4][6] = skip[6][4] = 5;
```

Can someone help explain why the following combination is not included in skip/jump?

```
skip[1][6] = skip[6][1] = 2;
skip[1][6] = skip[6][1] = 5;
```

Example
https://medium.com/@rebeccahezhang/leetcode-351-android-unlock-patterns-d9bae4a8a958

Comment: It looks like those special diagonals (not 45 degrees, like 6-1 or 2-7) are not counted as passing through other cells.

Comment: I assume `skip[1][3] = skip[3][1] = 2;` means that to go from 3->1 you **must** go through 2. You can go from 1-6 without going through any other key.

Answer (score -1):

```
function main() {
    console.time();
    let res = new Set();
    const matrix = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]];
    const dirs = [[-1, -1], [-1, 0], [-1, 1], [0, -1], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, -1]];
    let calls = { count: 0 };
    for (let i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            for (let k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
                helper(matrix, dirs, i, '', j, k, res, calls);
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(res.size, res.has('4136'), res.has('4192'), res.has('24136'), res.has('654192'), calls.count)
    // Ouputs: 348753 false false true true 78269073
    console.timeEnd();
}

function helper(matrix, dirs, length, word, si, sj, res, calls) {
    ++calls.count;
    if (si < 0 || si >= 3 || sj < 0 || sj >= 3 || length < 1) {
        return;
    }
    const key = `${matrix[si][sj]}`;
    if (word.includes(key)) {
        for (const [dx, dy] of dirs) {
            if (si + dx < 0 || si + dx >= 3 || sj + dy < 0 || sj + dy >= 3) {
                continue;
            }
            const key = `${matrix[si + dx][sj + dy]}`;
            if (word.includes(key)) {
                continue;
            }
            helper(matrix, dirs, length, word, si + dx, sj + dy, res, calls);
        }
        return;
    }
    if (length === 1) {
        res.add(word + key);
        return;
    }
    for (const [dx, dy] of dirs) {
        helper(matrix, dirs, length - 1, word + key, si + dx, sj + dy, res, calls);
    }
}

main();
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).